# iPhone SDK: Delegate method not getting called-Troubleshooting

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, delegates

If a Delegate method is not getting called, then what all things needs to be checked just to ensure that delegate is referenced in the viewController?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, for a start you have to conform to the protocol in your header:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <YOUR DELEGATE'S PROTOCOL HERE, 
                                                           UITableViewDelegate>{

}

@end
```

That's the most common mistake, anyway.

Also just make sure that you're setting your delegate. Normally you can do that like this:

```
myObject.delegate = self;
```

Though some classes do it in the initalization:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"MY APP"
                                                message:@"HELLO" 
                                               delegate:self 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"CLOSE" 
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for the input . This is all what we have to do? No other place we have to declare it right?

Comment: Not normally. Though as @occulus has said, you can often set the delegate directly from Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

If delegate methods aren't getting called when you are expecting them to, it's possible that you haven't actually hooked up the delegate. This can be done either in code, or in interface builder. For example, a `UITableView` in interface builder can have its `dataSource` and delegate outlets attached to a target, for example "File's owner".